# converting a click function to call function

Tags: javascript

I know this topic is asked before but they were not about jqueryui. Therefore I couldn't be sure will they work on my code. I have a pop up that is called from different components. But I have to write a click function for each call. I want to convert it to ca function that I can call it. My script is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a#popup').live('click', function (e) {

                var page = $(this).attr("href")

                var $dialog = $('<div id="silmeIframe"></div>')
                .html('<iframe  style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="500px" height="500px"></iframe>')
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    height: 'auto',
                    resizable: 'false',
                    width: 'auto',
                    title: "Silmeyi onaylıyor musunuz?",
                    close: function (event, ui) {

                        __doPostBack('<%= btnRefresh.ClientID %>', '');
                    }
                });
                $dialog.dialog('open');
                e.preventDefault();

            });

        });
    </script>
```

Now, I want it work like

```
<a onclick="NewFunctionName(parameter1,parameter2,,parameter3)">click<a/>
```

Comment: i don't get what's wrong with this one. why do you create handlers for each? jQuery can attach a single handler to multiple elements.

Comment: @Joseph there is nothing wrong, he just want to transform it

Comment: yes, I only want to transform it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[single handler, multiple targets attachment](http://jsfiddle.net/8JRRr/)

```
$(function () {

    function handler(e,param1,param2...) {
        var page = $(this).attr("href")
        ...
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    //write attachments
    $('a#popup1').on('click',function(e){
        handler(e,param1,param2...);
    });
    $('a#popup2').on('click',function(e){
        handler(e,param1,param2...);
    });
    $('a#popup3').on('click',function(e){
        handler(e,param1,param2...);
    });
});
```

[or single handler, multiple targets in one query](http://jsfiddle.net/wHDsD/)

```
$(function () {
    $('a#popup1, a#popup2, a#popup3').on('click',function (e) {
        var page = $(this).attr("href")
        ...
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried it. But I dont know how use handler in the first method. Do I have to write just like you wirte. Or inside the <a> tag?

Comment: @user1352563 just the way it is. you target the `<a>` when you attach (the parts with `a#popup`). you should avoid inline JavaScript in elements.

Comment: I have wrote it like that but it doesn't work. It opens the <a> tag href link on a new page. But it should be opened as a pop up. That is , I think, it does not see the popup id.

Comment: @user1352563 did you include an `e.preventDefault();` or `return false` at the end of your handler code? what does the console say? did you target the `<a>` properly?

Comment: I have deleted }); at last part because it gives syntax error. After that I tried putting document ready at the top of the script. Both of them did not work. And then I tried by deleting e.preventDefault();. there is no return false already.

Comment: I t has worked thanks so much. But I have last one question. is it possible to pass variables in it. I want the width and height to be dynamic.

Comment: @user1352563 i modified the first method. it now accepts additional parameters. you can't do this using the second method though.